# Xcode Slider Value Change +.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

As you may see from my code below, when I move my slider, the slider changes the value of the textfield by .1 .1 .1 .1. Meaning if I move a little over to the right the value may be 43.7. Is there a way that i can change the code to make it where it adds .5 .5 .5 5. So if i Move over it could be 43.5, 44, 44.5, 45. That kind of thing. Let me know if you have questions! Thanks for your help.

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
billAmountTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];
```

}

```
- (IBAction) changeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSString *textValue = [billAmountTextField text];
float value = [textValue floatValue];
if (value < 0) value = 0;
if (value > 100) value = 100;
mySlider.value = value;
billAmountTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", value];
if ([billAmountTextField canResignFirstResponder]) [billAmountTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

}

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
if (billAmountTextField) {
    if ([billAmountTextField canResignFirstResponder]) [billAmountTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You problem is when the 7th line of your code. You have set the value to go up and display increments of one decimal place. Try this:

```
billAmountTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", value];
```